# Crystal Report HTML text Interpretation alignment issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

i have a simple HTML code as

```
<div style="font-family: Segoe UI; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12; color: #000000;"> <p style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'; text-align: right;">Normal study</p> </div>
```

but when i show it by using crystal Report the word "Normal study" show on left side of report as text-align value are set as right. kindly help me.
i am using Crsytal Report 13.0.2 version
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Report has very limited support for HTML.  The "text-align" property is not supported.  You will need to use the alignment property of the field/object in your crystal report instead.